# External links opening in the non-default browser

Tags: firefox, default-programs, opera, default-browser

I have set Firefox as default web application in Ubuntu, but external links (like clicking a link in Pidgin) still get opened with Opera. Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: I would leave this as a comment but I don't have the permissions yet. Could you tell us:
how you set FireFox as the default (i.e. through system settings or in a prompt); and
is simply removing Opera from your system and option. Thanks

Comment: What is the default browser in Pidgin --> Preferences --> Browser

Comment: how you set FireFox as the default (i.e. through system settings or in a prompt); and is simply removing Opera from your system an option? (comment by [Garry Cairns](http://askubuntu.com/users/67788/garry-cairns) in answer)

Answer (score 1):

For Pidgin, it has a setting specifying which browser to use when opening links. For me, this was set to `Manual` for some reason, and it became so 'over night'.

You can find and change this setting by opening the buddy list window, going to `Tools > Preferences > Browser`. There select `Browser default` to use the system default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Default applications are specified in *All Settings* -> *Details* -> *Default Applications*.

If default Web browser is set there to Chrome, but links from other programs are still being opened with previously set default browser, this might be either some sort of a caching issue of Gnome, or 3rd party application - in your case Pidgin.

This is a blind guess, but I think I would try to reboot, and if still no result, would purge Pidgin and then reinstall.

Another option would be to remove Opera. Since you already have your favorite browser, most likely you don't need the other one, unless you have a special reasons for that.

Comment: Please elaborate your vote-down.

Comment: Quite a few down votes **without reasons**. Come on, that isn't fair or helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case - chromium wanted as default browser, but want also keep opera installed. Evince kept opening links in Opera, even I set chromium as default browser with `update-alternatives`. In my case helped setting `x-scheme-handler/http=chromium.desktop` to `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` as shown in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/152202/how-to-set-default-browser-for-pdf-reader-evince-on-linux/402409#402409).

Also the advice to run strace to see what is happening was useful.